# Getting collection and saving it into array object in firestore swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uikit

I'm trying to save collection into an array of objects called **List**, and the retrieving is been called in viewdidload by the function **loadfirebase**. So it actually retrieves the data from firebase and prints it but it doesn't save it in the array. I think it is something that deals with closure but not sure how to fix it.

```
//
//  ContactList.swift
//  Socket
//
//  Created by dalal aljassem on 12/16/21.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

class ContactList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private  let storage  = Storage.storage().reference()
   
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return List.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for:indexPath)
        var currentname = List[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentname.name
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        print("some action will happen when i tap here")
    }
    

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
       
        loadfirebase()
        print("**************",List)
    }
   
}
let database = Firestore.firestore()
func loadfirebase()
{
    let contactdataRef = database.collection("ContactData")
   contactdataRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
             //   var currentDoc = document.data()
                
                print("///////////////")
                // print("current doc = " , currentDoc)
                print("current name = " , document.get("name")!)
                print("current image = " , document.get("image")!)
            List.append(Contact(name: document.get("name") as! String, image: document.get("image") as! String, number: ""))
               
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }

   }}
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your List array is never initialized.
You can achieve this with the following code:

```
var List: [Contact] = []
```

and I would put this before the declaration of tableView function.

Comment: When i print the array its still empty? do you know what to do?

Comment: if you are referring to this code: `print("**************",List)`, then be aware that it will probably executed before loadfirebase(), because you have an asyncronous call in loadfirebase, that will finish way after the print statement. Try to print the list inside the getDocuments callback, it should work

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt save into the array